# Use a parameter to control the number of malings labels for a FetchXML based report?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, sql-server-data-tools, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to build a simple mailing label report that upon runtime lets the user choose the amount of labels to be generated for each record.

Solutionwize I'm thinking a report parameter is the way to go for the user to choose the amount of labels per record to be generated, but after that I'm kind of stuck.

The label itself will only contain 1 column, an ID.

Since it's a Dynamics 365 CRM online environment I have to find a solution without using SQL. I'm restricted to using only FetchXML and reporting services (SSDT).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if the number of mailing labels per record to create is reasonable low. If you need to create hundreds of labels for each record I would say this solution is too cumbersome.

This is how I managed to get it to work:

**Steps**

1. Create a "normal" mailing label-report: a list with the number of columns that matches the mailing label format you want to create.
2. Create a report parameter with **predefined values**, for example 1-10.
3. In the report designer, duplicate the number of rows in your list, so that you have the same amount as you specified earlier in the parameter you created in step 2. In my case I now have 10 rows.
4. Hide rows 2-10 so they are not visible unless the user selects the parameter value that corresponds to the number of rows to be shown. Create an expression for that. Just right click on the rown and under visability there's an option to show/hide based on expression.

**Expression example**

```
   Row 2: =IIF(Parameters!Amount.Value < 2, True, False)
   Row 3: =IIF(Parameters!Amount.Value < 3, True, False)
```

While this approach works and achieves my goal, it's not as elegant of a solution as I was hoping for. Would've been nicer to make the solution dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not SSRS expert, so I can't tell you how to do a repeating value based on parameter in report (without using coding in report which is prohibited in CRM Online reports), but the quite easy solution that I can see is creating a special Entity in CRM, let's call it Label. It should have two fields (aparat from default name field) - WholeNumber field (let's call it Count) and Lookup field (of the entity that you are printing this labels). Now simply create a plugin for Post-RetrieveMultiple of this Label entity - in this plugin based on provided Count and Lookup entity reference, you would simply create a list of Label entities and put it to your OutputParameter. Next it's simply creating SSRS report with proper FetchXML (which will have a parameter provided by a user and simply record id for which you are running report). Your plugin will return as much records as you want, so you simply grab them and display in your report in a tablix. To give you an idea what I'm talking about here is some sample code for the plugin:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{

    var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    var query = (QueryExpression)context.InputParameters["Query"];
    //get values from your query
    int labelsToGenerate = 10;
    var label = new Entity("new_label");
    /////

    label["new_name"] = Guid.NewGuid();

    var labelCollection = new EntityCollection();
    labelCollection.Entities.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(label, labelsToGenerate));

    context.OutputParameters["EntityCollection"] = labelCollection;
}
```

Remember that for this to work, it must be on Post-Operation of RetrieveMultiple message.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest dropping the report approach to instead create a smart webresource that will accept fetchxml for the selection of records (either plain xml or reference to an existing view) and a count parameter.

Comment: That's not a bad idea! It would've been a flexible way to solve the problem, and not to break the laws of physics (crm).

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to find an easy way to do this. While I suspect that some creative solution exists, I think it is unrelated to FetchXML - i.e. it would involve making SSRS repeat a value based on a number in a parameter.

I also suspect that repeating the output an arbitrary number of times inside the same report could produce alignment challenges.

Instead of getting involved with a report parameter and SSRS programming, perhaps consider making a simple, well-aligned report that produces a single label. When the users go to print they can use the print dialog to specify how many copies they want.

Comment: I'm believe you're right, that it might be unrelated to FetchXML, but a few examples I've found while googling around involves modifying the SQL-query with UNIONS etc. That's the reason I wanted to mention that I have to use FetchXML.

Comment: Yes, I saw those SQL unions as well, and briefly experimented unsuccessfully with FetchXML's "top" attribute.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence in your answer: I can't go that way since the users might want to print let's say 20 copies of one label. That would be 20 pages with 1 label on each page, which is not how they expect the report to behave.

Comment: OK. What is the label printing situation? Are they using sheets with multiple labels, or individual labels, or an actual label printer? I guess my answer kind of assumes one of the latter two options.

Comment: It's the first of the three: "sheets with multiple labels", so we want to maximize the use of those sheets, so we don't waste sheets with empty labels.